# CSS Not Updating with W3 Total Cache and Amazon CloudFront - Seeking Solutions

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, w3-total-cache

CSS Not Updating with W3 Total Cache and Amazon CloudFront - Seeking Solutions

Hello! I've encountered an issue while working with the combination of the W3 Total Cache plugin and the Amazon CloudFront CDN service. The problem isn't with the configuration itself, as that seems to be set up correctly. The trouble arises when adding a new page template with fresh styles to the project. Despite these styles being present in the S3 bucket, the W3 Total Cache plugin seems to persistently serve an outdated version of the CSS, not reflecting the recent changes. Strangely, it takes a day or two for the new styles to finally show up, which is far from ideal.

Furthermore, I've come across another perplexing problem. Even though I've disabled plugin caching in the settings (as seen here: [[link to screenshot]](https://prnt.sc/PltrQ88a0l3m)), W3 Total Cache continues attempting to fetch plugin styles from URLs like "3w5782fermyc3.cloudfront.net/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7", leading to a slew of console errors.

I've dedicated a considerable amount of time yesterday in search of a solution, delving through a plethora of information, but unfortunately, nothing has worked so far. Perhaps someone else has encountered a similar issue or could recommend resources where I can find information about configuring W3 Total Cache effectively. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!